# Uncaught ReferenceError: infowindow is not defined #googleMaps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, runtime-error

I'm trying to integrate the Google maps API to my page. I use a code that extract the locations from JSON and saves the location in an array, then return the place-data of each location. Everything went well except I can't activate the `infowindow` function when clicking on marker on the map. This is the error that appears when clicking:

[image]

```js
var map;    // declares a global map variable


/*
Start here! initializeMap() is called when page is loaded.
*/
function initializeMap() {

  var locations;

  var mapOptions = {
    disableDefaultUI: true
  };

  /*
  For the map to be displayed, the googleMap var must be
  appended to #mapDiv in resumeBuilder.js.
  */
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('#map'), mapOptions);


  /*
  locationFinder() returns an array of every location string from the JSONs
  written for bio, education, and work.
  */
  function locationFinder() {

    // initializes an empty array
    var locations = [];

    // adds the single location property from bio to the locations array
    locations.push(bio.contacts.location);

    // iterates through school locations and appends each location to
    // the locations array. Note that forEach is used for array iteration
    // as described in the Udacity FEND Style Guide:
    // https://udacity.github.io/frontend-nanodegree-styleguide/javascript.html#for-in-loop
    education.schools.forEach(function(school){
      locations.push(school.location);
    });

    // iterates through work locations and appends each location to
    // the locations array. Note that forEach is used for array iteration
    // as described in the Udacity FEND Style Guide:
    // https://udacity.github.io/frontend-nanodegree-styleguide/javascript.html#for-in-loop
    work.jobs.forEach(function(job){
      locations.push(job.location);
    });

    return locations;
  }

  /*
  createMapMarker(placeData) reads Google Places search results to create map pins.
  placeData is the object returned from search results containing information
  about a single location.
  */
  function createMapMarker(placeData) {

    // The next lines save location data from the search result object to local variables
    var lat = placeData.geometry.location.lat();  // latitude from the place service
    var lng = placeData.geometry.location.lng();  // longitude from the place service
    var name = placeData.formatted_address;   // name of the place from the place service
    var bounds = window.mapBounds;            // current boundaries of the map window


    // infoWindows are the little helper windows that open when you click
    // or hover over a pin on a map. They usually contain more information
    // about a location.
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: name
    });

    // marker is an object with additional data about the pin for a single location
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: placeData.geometry.location,
      title:  name
    });


    // hmmmm, I wonder what this is about...
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      // your code goes here!
       infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    // this is where the pin actually gets added to the map.
    // bounds.extend() takes in a map location object
    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
    // fit the map to the new marker
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    // center the map
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
  }

  /*
  callback(results, status) makes sure the search returned results for a location.
  If so, it creates a new map marker for that location.
  */
  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      createMapMarker(results[0]);
    }
  }

  /*
  pinPoster(locations) takes in the array of locations created by locationFinder()
  and fires off Google place searches for each location
  */
  function pinPoster(locations) {

    // creates a Google place search service object. PlacesService does the work of
    // actually searching for location data.
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    // Iterates through the array of locations, creates a search object for each location
      locations.forEach(function(place){
      // the search request object
      var request = {
        query: place
      };

      // Actually searches the Google Maps API for location data and runs the callback
      // function with the search results after each search.
      service.textSearch(request, callback);
    });
  }

  // Sets the boundaries of the map based on pin locations
  window.mapBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  // locations is an array of location strings returned from locationFinder()
  locations = locationFinder();

  // pinPoster(locations) creates pins on the map for each location in
  // the locations array
  pinPoster(locations);

}

/*
Uncomment the code below when you're ready to implement a Google Map!
*/

// Calls the initializeMap() function when the page loads
window.addEventListener('load', initializeMap);

// Vanilla JS way to listen for resizing of the window
// and adjust map bounds
window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {
  // Make sure the map bounds get updated on page resize
 map.fitBounds(mapBounds);
});
```

Comment: `infowindow` -> `infoWindow` at lines `// your code goes here!
       infowindow.open(map, marker);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to create an `infoWindow` object here:

```
// infoWindows are the little helper windows that open when you click
// or hover over a pin on a map. They usually contain more information
// about a location.
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: name
});
```

and then work with it (show message after marker click)

```
// hmmmm, I wonder what this is about...
marker.addListener('click', function() {
  // your code goes here!
   infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

But look at your variables attentively:
`infoWindow !== infowindow` (letter `W`)

browser doesn't know, what info**w**indow is, and falls with an error.

Read more about variables naming in JS here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Declarations

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while trying to debug some code that I had copied from the Udacity tutorial (Getting Started with the APIs) that Hasam was drawing from.  My code, as copied from the video itself, lacked some key lines, and wouldn't run correctly. The tutorial's 'resources' didn't have a copy of the code. I eventually  found a good copy of the code on Github: https://github.com/udacity/ud864. As I wrote this answer, I found the same link tucked away on the bottom of *some* of the Udacity tutorial pages themselves.